# tcsetattr(TCSAFLUSH) is not behaving as expected

Tags: python, terminal, tty, termios

I have a Python program that switches to cbreak mode, and then uses terminal escape codes to turn the mouse position reporting on and off. In cbreak mode, the "echoing" of input is turned off, so the expected behaviour is to NOT see any of the mouse position reporting echoed in stdout.

However, I am seeing some issue during teardown. Basically, I first *disable* the mouse (by writing the corresponding escape code to stdout), and then switch *off* cbreak mode -- but some mouse position reporting is still being echoed, generating some garbage in stdout. This indicates that the disabling of the mouse took effect AFTER turning off cbreak.

After disabling the mouse, I have tried a number of different things to "flush" (that is, block until all output written to stdout is sent to terminal) before turning stdin cbreak mode off, but the only thing that seems to work is a "sleep".

My question is:

- What am I supposed to do, after writing mouse disable escape code to stdout, and before setting stdin cbreak mode off, so that I don't get garbage echoed to stdout accidentally?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import termios
import tty
import sys
import os
import time
import fcntl

# turning off buffering does not fix problem
# sys.stdout = os.fdopen(os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno()), 'wb', buffering=0)

term_in = sys.stdin.fileno()
term_out = sys.stdout.fileno()

# setting stdout to nonblocking does not fix problem
# old_flags = fcntl.fcntl(term_out, fcntl.F_GETFL)
# fcntl.fcntl(term_out, fcntl.F_SETFL, old_flags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

term_mode = termios.tcgetattr(term_in)
tty.setcbreak(term_in)

enable_mouse = b"\x1b[?1000;1004;1005;1006;1003h"
os.write(term_out, enable_mouse)

time.sleep(1)  # move mouse while waiting

# First disable mouse
disable_mouse = b"\x1b[?1003;1006;1005;1004;1000l"
os.write(term_out, disable_mouse)

# manually drain does not fix problem
# termios.tcdrain(term_out)
# termios.tcdrain(term_in)

# manual sendbreak does not fix problem
# termios.tcsendbreak(term_in, 0)
# termios.tcsendbreak(term_out, 0)

# this does actually fix the problem, surprisingly?!?
# time.sleep(0.1)

# problem here: After disable mouse, switch out of cbreak (enables echo)
# expected behaviour: no mouse events are echoed in stdout
termios.tcsetattr(term_in, termios.TCSAFLUSH, term_mode)
```

Comment: You should clarify what you expect to accomplish when you use the term *"flush"*.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596242/pyserial-when-should-i-use-flush/61602365#61602365

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question hopefully in a way that makes it clear.

Comment: As I tried to point out in the linked answer, TCSAFLUSH will (immediately) discard all buffered input and/or output.  If you want to *"block until all output written"*, then that seems a lot more tike the **tcdrain()** syscall.  That would behave like a **sleep()** but with a variable duration determined by the output flow.  *"manually drain does not fix problem"* -- A summation that lacks any details.  Perhaps the *"problem"* is something else?  FYI there's  no syscall to drain input, so that should have generated an error.  As a rule, always check return codes, esp when things don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the terminal modes is done in the operating system - not the terminal. You can ensure that the terminal's up to date by ending your output by sending an escape sequence which requires a response, e.g, cursor-position-report, and reading **that** back.

Answer (score 0):

> This indicates that the disabling of the mouse took effect AFTER turning off cbreak.

A perfectly plausible situation.
Draining the output only concerns local events that your system can control & monitor.  Your program would still have to account for the reception and processing of this new directive by the mouse itself to change its operating mode.

Your program expects this external processing (by the mouse) to occur instantaneously after transmission has completed.
No, the processing won't happen that fast.
Draining (to accommodate transmission time) plus a finite delay/sleep (to accommodate mouse processing time) may be the correct solution.